# How to convert C# class into a Async Queryable?

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I have a method:

```
public async Task<int> CountCust(IQueryable<Cust> cust, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     ......
     ......
  totalCount = await cust.Where(.....).CountAsync(cancellationToken);
     ......
     ...... 
}
```

Cust is class:

```
public class Cust
{
    ......
}
```

I've tried:

```
        Cust cust = new();
        var CustListQ = new List<Cust> { cust };
        var CustListQ  = CustListQ.AsQueryable();
```

And use CustListQ as the input argument.  But it complains that CustListQ has not implemented Async.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.'

So do I get a async CustListQ from the class ?

Thanks.

Comment: there's no point in an async-operation on a `List<T>` and this is why you probably get the error. While you can of course query a list, you can't do so aynchronously, because - well, there's no resource despite your memory associated to that list. Async operations typically involve IO-operations, e.g. querying a database.

Comment: Obviously, you must have a DbContext from the Entity Framework. Accordingly, you must pass a DbSet from this context to this method. Something like: `CountCust(context.Custs, `

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  I understand now.  I thought the input to the methods was a request from the front-end.  But it's actually from the database DBSet.  Thanks a lot, a lot !!!